# java POST 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I am trying to get the values of a field from a jsp to a spring mvc controller.  The values from the jsp are not in a form, so I can't use HttpServletRequest to get the values directly.  So I get the values in js using document.getElementById('fieldName').value, create an object, strigify it and send it to the controller using AJAX.  However, I am getting a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error.  Below is my js code and controller code:

```
function getInput(){
    var ageMin=document.getElementById('age_min').value;
    var ageMax=document.getElementById('age_max').value;
    var creditMin=document.getElementById('credit_min').value;
    var obj = {"ageMin":ageMin,"ageMax":ageMax, "creditMin":creditMin};
    console.log(obj);
    var sobj=JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(sobj);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/login/validate.mvc",
        type: 'POST',
        data: sobj,  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(results) {
        }
    });     
}


Controller:


    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate.mvc", method = RequestMethod.POST )
        public void getValidate(@RequestBody Object sobj){  

            System.out.println(sobj);
        }
```

Comment: Why Object? And why not a proper class that reflects JS object you are receiving via `@RequestBody`?

Comment: because I am receiving a proper object.  just fields from a jsp page. no form is present in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just specify the data type attribute and it will solve your problem

```
datatype : "json",
```

Comment: Is your controller expecting the content type as json only?

Comment: can you paste your json here

Comment: I guess so... I am sending all the field values as an object which does not exist in my project.  I have to pass via Ajax as these values are not in a field.

Comment: can you paste your controller code here.just to see what is happening there

Comment: JSON: Object {ageMin: "5", ageMax: "5", creditMin: "1000"}  Stringify:  {"ageMin":"5","ageMax":"5","creditMin":"1000"}

Comment: the controller:  @RequestMapping(value = "/validate.mvc", method = RequestMethod.POST )
        public void getValidate(@RequestBody Object sobj){  

            System.out.println(sobj);
        }

Comment: are you using any kind of library here like jackson etc?

Comment: try using String or any specific bean object class instead of Object in the requestBody

Comment: yes you should as this might be the serialization error... but before that just try replacing the Object class to String..If this doesn't work then use Jackson library

Comment: ok. I replaced Object with String but this time I am getting 404 error not found for the path "http://localhost:8080/login/validate.mvc"

Comment: check your mapping now..is your controller properly mapped with the url u are sending

Comment: http://localhost:8080/temptingplaces-web/login/validate.mvc you have given this link in your ajax...what is the expected url in your controller?

Comment: In the mapping, I changed it to /login/validate.mvc.  However now, I get the 500 (Internal Server Error)... I am sorry, am I supposed to get all these errors?  I even changed the mapping to : "localhost:8080/temptingplaces-web/login/validate.mvc"

Comment: thats internal server error which means your request is reaching the controller but there is some issue in your controller. remove datatype : "json" from your ajax if you are not expecting any response from the server

Comment: Removed. and the contentType?  I changed it to : contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" should have worked.But yes you can always try all the possible option.did it worked?

Comment: Same 500 (Internal Server Error) and yes I am working on spring mvc.